# Centering field in <p> won't work

Tags: html, css

I am no good in wrinting UIs in pure html... Right now I am trying to create a simple login page in pure html in css, but somehow I cannot get the Login button from here https://jsfiddle.net/2oxz5oja/ to be centered.

```
p {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Does this style work for  table-row elements?

Could someone here give me an advice?

Comment: dont use `display:table-row`.  If you _must_ use tables, use tables.  Otherwise, work with `block`, `inline`, and `inline-block` elements.

what you're trying to approximate here is a `table-cell`, not a `table-row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I'm having some issues with my *Fiddle*. So I've copy/pasted it here.

Try this:

> HTML

```
 <h3>Login here</h3>

<div id="loginMenu" class="mainDiv">
    <form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post" action="/konferencje-web/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="hidden" name="login-form" value="login-form" />
        <p>
            <label for="login-form:login" class="input-form">Login:</label>
            <input id="login-form:login" type="text" name="login-form:login" class="input-form" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="login-form:password" class="input-form">Password:</label>
            <input id="login-form:password" type="password" name="login-form:password" value="" class="input-form" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="login-form:button" class = "login" type="submit" name="login-form:button" value="Login" />
        </p>
        <p>
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('login-form'),{'login-form:j_idt21':'login-form:j_idt21'},'');return false">Info page</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

</html>
```

> CSS

```
   body {
        background-color: #6B2424;
    }
    form {
        display: table;
    }
    input {
        display: table-cell;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    label {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    p {
        display: table-row;
        text-align: center;
    }
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        line-height: 150%;
    }
    a {
        color: #000000;
        line-height: 30px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1, h3 {
        color: wheat;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    select {
        min-width: 150px;
    }
    #login-form {
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%
    }
    .mainDiv {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: bisque;
        width: 500px;
        border:2px solid;
        border-radius:25px;
        line-height: 30px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .login
    {
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having issues with JSFiddle today too. Don't forget though that you can include a live "Stack Snippet" that functions similarly to JSFiddle by clicking the JS/HTML/CSS snippet button in the editor window.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeiste Thankyou for the heads up, will try that next time :)